# App for meeting agenda tracking

Tags: time-management

I'm looking for an app (web/mobile/desktop, anyway) that can track meeting agenda. I'd like it to show planned time blocks and where we are currently. Google Calendar already behaves similarly, but I'd like it to work at smaller scale - minutes and seconds.

Comment: By "app" you are referring to an Android/iOS/Windows app?

Comment: Platform doesn't matter so much

Comment: As far as I know, Google Calendar works at a resolution of 1 minute. In what way do you find Google Calendar inappropriate?

Comment: Hmm, you are right, interesting... Although the problem is that the time of meeting is shown as very little 1-hour rectangle. And that's not easy to track 2- and 1-minute parts of it.